# jQuery .each best practice to format and send via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What is the best practice to run .each and send the value as an array via ajax.

```
 $( ".sortable li" ).each(function( index ) {
      console.log($(this).data("trackid"));
 });
```

This will output in a console window 11,2,45,23,4,31.

Comment: Depends on the listening end. Besides the given code does not use AJAX

Comment: i know it doesnt use ajax, i just want to know the best practice to put it into an array so that I can send the json formatted array via ajax. thanks.

Comment: Guess not psychic as JSON is not mentioned - so should be [11,2,...]

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use the push method to add the id's to an array. I've posted an array like this to PHP and it works well.

```
 var theArray = [];
 $( ".sortable li" ).each(function( index ) {
     theArray.push($(this).data("trackid"));
 });

 // Send via Ajax
 $.post(url,{ids:theArray},function(response){
     // Code to handle response
 });
```